# Weird DNS queries to messager.xicp.net

Tags: dns, trojan

A DNS query for this domain (messager.xicp.net) was classified and detected as "Trojan.Generic.DNS" by the FireEye NX  in our network.

So, I used both VirusTotal and abuseibdb sites to check this domain. It seems it's mapped to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and when I ping this domain it pings my localhost IP. **Could you explain this behavior?**

I tried using viewDNS to trace route and I got this output:

> traceroute to messager.xicp.net (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte
>   packets 1 obfuscated.internal.network.com (0.0.0.0) 0.000 ms 0.000 ms
>   0.000 ms 2 obfuscated.internal.network.com (0.0.0.0) 1.000 ms 1.000 ms 1.000 m

**Could you please explain this behavior, why it's mapped to 127.0.0.1** (It wasn't like this according to the results from VirusTotal as it was mapped to this IP 174.128.255.245 on 2018-04-11)

Comment: why this domain messager.xicp.net is mapped to localhost (127.0.0.1)?? Here's the most important point. Also, is there an IoC for this domain? @schroeder

Comment: Any domain-based IoCs will be listed on the sites you used to check it.

Comment: What you want to know is why *FireEye* flagged it. That's a question for the alert and their support.

Comment: @schroeder, No, I want to know why it's mapped to LocalHost? and why when I ping the domain (messager.xicp.net)  from my PC it pings my localhost??

Comment: Ok, then my answer is that answer.

Comment: @schroeder, thank you then, perhaps other people will comment or answer differently, let's wait and see. thanks for your contribution

Comment: @ibr2 have you set anything in the hosts file regarding that domain? Can you check the file?

Comment: @SirMuffington, No, Nothing has changed. Also, it's even resolved to 127.0.0.1 in VirusTotal, so it global not local

Comment: @ibr2 I guess the A record is set to localhost then.

Comment: @SirMuffington, I kinda get it, however, is it possible to do that??

Comment: @ibr2 clearly it is. I can tell that it's even possible to set an A record to an arbitrary private IP address

Answer (score 2):

Domains getting mapped to localhost is common when you want to route traffic destined to an external domain to the local machine first for proxying/inspecting/modification.

There are valid reasons for doing so, but it is also a method used by malware for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Subdomains under .xicp.net fallback to 127.0.0.1 unless otherwise configured. The parent domain is the main culprit here, and probably the reason why it was flagged. If you [search virustotal for xicp.net](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/domain/xicp.net/details) you will get more informative results.

Also searching googe for .xicp.net returns many results where a subdomain has been used as a c2 server.

Comment: Great, however, I'd like to know why it's resolved to (127.0.0.1). Also, does it indicate that it's malicious?